# CSV files remain open when created by spark DataFrameWriter

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to edit some large csv files and then write them back to hdfs using spark DataFrameWriter. Everything looks fine, but after the script is finished, when I want to open the edited csv files (they're in partitions) it gives me warning that the swap file already exists. I don't know why the file is still open after the script is done.

```
 df = sqlContext.read.load(f, header='true', sep = '|', format='com.databricks.spark.csv')
 df = df.withColumn('YEAR', lit(year))

 df.write.option("sep","|").option("header","true").csv(dir)
```

I couldn't find any explicit close for that. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You haven't posted any of your code or your tracebacks, how do you expect us to help?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jtwilson Your'e right, sorry, I just edited my post.

Comment: this is not very helpful.  there is no way for anyone to know what these variables are or for us to try to reproduce the issue.  please actually read what i posted

Comment: @jtwilson I don't know how the rest of my code would be helpful, the actual work is done with these three lines. I'm loading a file from hdfs into dataframe, and after adding a new column I'm writing it back to hdfs. What else should I add?